Selecting a high-speed HDMI connector
I'm looking to build a mostly-passthrough HDMI device, but I'm finding it very confusing to understand the maximum speed that a connector can allow for.
I've noticed that DigiKey, for example, shows "HDMI 2.1" support for certain parts. However, for many parts, the manufacturer does not mention anything about bandwidth. This is a representative example of what the datasheet shows, from the QJ51191-LFB4-7F, datasheet:



#
Description
Specifications
Additional Information




19
T.M.D.S Signals time domain impedance
- Standard: ANSI/EIA-364-108  - Rise time: ≤200ps (10%-90%)  - Signal to Ground pin ratio: per HDMI designation  - Measurement: Differential Measurement  - Specimen Environment impedance: =100Ω differential  - Connector Mounting: Source-side receptacle connector mounted on a controlled impedance PCB fixture
- Connector Area: 100Ω ±15%  - Transition Area: 100Ω ±15%  - Cable Area: 100Ω ±10%


20
T.M.D.S Signals time domain cross talk FEXT
- Standard: ANSI/EIA-364-90  - Rise time: ≤200ps (10%-90%)  - Signal to Ground pin ratio: per HDMI designation  - Measurement: Differential Measurement  - Specimen Environment impedance: =100Ω differential  - Connector Mounting: Source-side receptacle connector mounted on a controlled impedance PCB fixture  - Test Configuration: Driven pair and victim pair
Maximum FEXT: 5% maximum.



How can I select a connector that is suitable for a given bandwidth?
Does it even matter what connector is used?

+1 for a properly formatted Markdown table!

The connector shouldn’t matter since HDMI 2.x uses the same connector as HDMI 1.x. I’d be more concerned about the PCB layout and the board stackup so you can retain the proper 100ohm impedance of the 5 differential pairs on your board.

@SteKulov Not correct. You have connectors officially rated for some bandwidth. You can't use HDMI 1.X approved connector for HDMI 2.1.

While nominal impedance is ok, it's tested at a much longer rise time than the part would actually be used with. There is also no attenuation spec. My guess is it will work but you're running a part where it wasn't characterized so there is a risk it fails.

@Justme  Whoops!  You are indeed correct in the official sense via the official testing protocol.  I forgot that the CDF (capabilities declaration form) requires you to list the HDMI connector model number(s) used within your product so they can cross-check it with their approved list.  I just wanted to stress that the PCB layout is likely going to have a bigger impact on the performance than the connector.  It sounded like a one-off hobby project to me, so I assumed this wasn't going to go through any official testing (probably a bad assumption by me).

@SteKulov seems like you've answered my question in the comments :)
I'm definitely concerned about the layout as well, but I can research that part myself. It's a one-off hobby project, so I don't have the equipment to debug it. I'd like to get it right first time.

@flaviut  Justme's answer addresses your question directly. I just wanted to add more context that the layout will have more effect than the connector. I am an official HDMI adopter, and I have to admit a lot of the "official" stuff seems like kind of a racket from my experience. My hunch is that a bunch of connectors on the 1.x list would probably easily pass testing to be put on the 2.x list. But it's not worth it for the manufacturer to pay for all the additional fees, royalties, and testing so they opt out. But, user1850479's comment should be noted that it might not be worth the risk.

You choose a connector based on what you need. Connectors rated for HDMI 2.1 by manufacturer are likely on the list of officially approved connector for HDMI 2.1 which goes up to 12 Gbps per lane. HDMI 2.0 goes up to 6 Gbps per lane and HDMI 1.4 up to 3.4 Gbps per lane.
Connectors not having a rating are either intended for slower speeds that were the fastest back then, or completely unapproved for official use.
You can check the list of approved connectors to find if your mystery connectors are there, or you can find connector manufacturer list for the speed grade or contact the manufacturer for what you need.
And this connector is not on the HDMI 2.1 list but is in the standard connector list.
